# NextJS TypeError related to UseStates and Array.map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, next.js

I've been encountering an issue for a while now when trying to map an array in my NextJS project. The error I have been encountering is:

```html
⨯ src\app\delivery\cart\page.tsx (30:9) @ map
 ⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')
    at Cart (./src/app/delivery/cart/page.tsx:36:18)
  28 |                  <Navbar />
  29 |                  <p className="text-4xl p-4">Cart</p>
> 30 |                  {cart.map((item) => (
     |                       ^
  31 |                          <div key={crypto.randomUUID()}>
  32 |                                  <p>{item.name}</p>
  33 |                                  <p>{item.price}</p>
```

The reason why I am confused is because everything is rendered properly. My best guess is that there is a split second where my `cart` useState variable is null, and therefore this error pops up. Here is the code for `cart/page.tsx`:

```js
"use client";

import Navbar from "@/components/delivery/navbar";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Cart() {
    const cartFromLocalStorage =
        typeof window !== "undefined"
            ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart") || "[]")
            : null;

    const [cart, setCart] = useState<
        {
            name: string;
            imgSrc: string;
            price: number;
            id: number;
            amount: number;
        }[]
    >(cartFromLocalStorage);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
    }, [cart]);

    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <p className="text-4xl p-4">Cart</p>
            {cart.map((item) => (
                <div key={crypto.randomUUID()}>
                    <p>{item.name}</p>
                    <p>{item.price}</p>
                    <p>{item.id}</p>
                    <p>{item.amount}</p>
                </div>
            ))}
        </>
    );
}
```

I've attempted to fix the issue by checking if `cart` exists with the following code.

```js
{cart ? cart.map((item)=> (...)) : "<p> No Items in Cart </p>"}
```

I have also changed the

```js
const cartFromLocalStorage =
        typeof window !== "undefined"
            ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart") || "[]")
            : null;
```

to

```js
const cartFromLocalStorage =
        typeof window !== "undefined"
            ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart") || "[]")
            : [];
```

but both attempts have led to hydration errors from NextJS. This has been driving me crazy and I haven't  been able to find a solid fix for it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `const cartFromLocalStorage = typeof window !== "undefined" && localStorage["cart"] && JSON.parse(localStorage["cart"]) ?? [];`

Comment: @AluanHaddad I think you may have mixed up something in your line of code because that doesn't actually set `cartFromLocalStorage` to any value. Any clarifications would be very appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try using conditional operator before map method. it will handle the initial undefined value until data was rendered

```
cart?.map((item) => (
```

Comment: Unfortunately this leads to hydration errors from NextJS similar to the `cart ? cart.map()` attempt.